# Use nested var for substitute var

Tags: bash, variable-substitution, syntax

I've a big question today ! I've made a little exemple of my situation.

```
FOO="foo";
fooBAR="final";

var=${${FOO}BAR}
echo $var
```

I want to print "final". I tried all sort of things like ${${!FOO@}BAR} (I know it's not correct) and I didn't found any solution to my problem. Ideally I don't want to pass via temporary variable/eval.

Comment: what is the problem with eval ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was for passing argument to an other function, the best way i found :

```
local CLIENT_URL="${CLIENT}_URL"
local CLIENT_FOLDER="${CLIENT}_FOLDER"
local CLIENT_BIN_PATH="${CLIENT}_BIN_PATH"
installClient   ${UPDATE_OS_PACKAGES}\
                ${USER_NAME}\
                ${GROUP_NAME}\
                ${!CLIENT_URL}\
                ${!CLIENT_FOLDER}\
                ${!CLIENT_BIN_PATH}
```

This was for this reason I doesn't wanted to use temporary var or eval. (Sorry to answer 2 weeks after.)

Answer (score 2):

There will have to be some runtime code evaluation in any case

```
eval "var=\${${FOO}BAR}"
printf '%s\n' "$var"
```

Or without the temporary `var`:

```
eval "printf '%s\n' \"\${${FOO}BAR}\""
```

If your worry is that `$FOO` may contain other things than a variable name (like `foo=$(reboot)` which could have bad consequences), you'd want to do the sanitizing by hand before hand like:

```
valid_variable() {
  local LC_ALL=C
  case $1 in
    ("" | *[![:alnum:]]* | [0-9]*) return 1
  esac
}

valid_variable "${FOO}BAR" || exit 1
eval "printf '%s\n' \"\${${FOO}BAR}\""
```

With `zsh`, you could do:

```
printf '%s\n' ${(P):-${FOO}BAR}}
```

but you'd still want to sanitize the value of `$FOO` if it's not trusted as values like `x[0$(reboot)]` would still be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
var=${FOO}BAR
## to print
eval echo \$$var
## to set
somevar=$(eval echo \$$var)
```

Comment: You're missing quotes. Here twice for each of those `eval` commands. Once for the `eval` command (for `$var`), and another time for the resulting `echo` command (for its `$fooBAR` variable). `eval "echo \"\${$var}\""`